# Is there a command line way to detect uninstalled drivers in devicemanger?

Tags: command-line-interface, drivers, device-manager, devcon, adb-drivers

I am trying to find a command line way to detect uninstalled drivers in `device manager`, I need a way to detect if there are items under "other devices" as shown below screen shot

[image: otherdeices]

Answer (score 2):

Couple out of the box (mostly) options here;

**Command Prompt (Admin)**

```
C:\> wmic path win32_pnpentity where ConfigManagerErrorcode!=0 get * /format:list
```

**Powershell**

```
PS C:\> Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPEntity | where {$_.status -ne "OK"} | fl
```

---

Using the properties from the above results, you can customise the output;

```
C:\> wmic path win32_pnpentity where ConfigManagerErrorcode!=0 get pnpclass,name,status /format:list
```

```
PS C:\> Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPEntity | where {$_.status -ne "OK"} | ft pnpclass,name,status -AutoSize
```

**Note** No pipe on the `wmic` example.

You can get more information about output formats using;

```
C:\> wmic path win32_pnpentity where ConfigManagerErrorcode!=0 get * /format /?
```

and

```
PS C:\> get-help format
```

**Update:**

In regards to listing specifically "uninstalled" devices (your post addressed both "other" and "uninstalled" devices, which are technically different), have a read of the microsoft class description for `win32_pnpentity`,

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394353(v=vs.85).aspx

> **Properties** 
>   The Win32_PnPEntity class has these properties.
>
> ......
>
> Other (1)
>
> Unknown (2)
>
> Running/Full Power (3)
>
> ...
>
> **Not Installed (11)**
>
> ...

Comment: None of those answers actually address the question. As shown in OP picture those devices are not recognized on `status` as *not ok*. They can be either.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct way to find *problem* devices that show up in Windows *Device Manager* with a question sign under **"Other devices"**.

First thing to note is that these devices are not really problem devices, only that they have not been assigned a **`classGuid`**.  The tricky part is that powershell doesn't seem to like *empty* (`""`) strings in the test, so you need to use the Null test: `[string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.ClassGuid)`,like this.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPEntity | Where-Object{[string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.ClassGuid) } |Select-Object Name,Present,Status,DeviceID |Sort-Object Name
```

With Output:

```bash
Name              Present Status DeviceID
----              ------- ------ --------
                     True OK     HTREE\ROOT\0
Airoha_APP           True OK     BTHENUM\{8901DFA8-5C7E-4D8F-9F0C-C2B70683F5F0}_VID&0002054C_PID&0D58\7&2CE6D2A4&0&F84E17E86153_C00000000
Amazon Alexa         True OK     BTHENUM\{931C7E8A-540F-4686-B798-E8DF0A2AD9F7}_VID&0002054C_PID&0D58\7&2CE6D2A4&0&F84E17E86153_C00000000
```

<sub>PS. I leave it as an exercise to filter out the ROOT hub.
Which is a kind way of saying I'm too lazy to do it myself.</sub>

For a slightly different list including *Non present* and/or with `unknown` status, try this:

```
Get-PnPDevice | Where-Object{[string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.ClassGuid) } | Select-Object FriendlyName,Present,Status,DeviceID | Sort-Object FriendlyName
```